# Probability $(|X-1| \ge 1)$ with $X ~ Unif(0,1)$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given $X_1,...,X_{100}$ ~ iid Unif(0,1), with $X_{n:n}$ being the largest order statistic, I'm asked to show for $n=100$ and some $\epsilon > 0$, $P(|X_{n:n}-1|\ge 1) = P(X_{n:n} \ge 1-\epsilon)$.

I'm totally lost however, because I'm coming to the conclusion that the statement is not true:
$P(|X_{n:n}-1|\ge 1) = P(X_{n:n} \ge 2) + P(X_{n:n} \le 0) = 0 + P(X_{n:n} \le 0) = P(X_{n:n} < 0) + P(X_{n:n}=0)= 0 + 0 = 0$, because the distribution ranges from $0 \le x \le 1$, and given it's a continuous distribution, the probability any $x$ takes any exact value i.e. $x=0$ is 0.

Yet clearly $P(X_{n:n} \ge 1-\epsilon)$ is non-zero (right?). I would think the previous inequality always takes on a range (as opposed to exact value), a range like $(0.9999999999999,1)$ is still a range, so the probability would be non-zero. How would I show the inequality does in fact equal 0? (I assume it must, because I think my initial calculations were correct).

Comment: Isn't it $0$ simply because the distribution for $X$ cannot take values less than $0$? Only values in the range $0 \le X \le 1$?

Comment: I agree that what you are asked to show is false for the reasons you gave.  Is it possible you misread part of the problem?

Comment: Word for word, the problem was posted as:

-1- Suppose $X_1,...,X_{100}$ ~ iid $Unif(0,1)$ and $X_{n:n}$ is the largest order statistic.
For $n=100$ and for some $\epsilon>0$, show that $P(|X_{n:n}-1| \ge 1)=P(X_{n:n} \ge 1- \epsilon)$ :/

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why the definition would lead to $P(X_{n:n}<0) = \frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: Oh, wait, never mind. I misread the probability distribution as normal, not uniform. Forget everything I wrote.

Comment: Haha no problem. Happy that my confusion from it was only short-lived

Comment: Is it possible that $Unif$ takes $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ so that it doesn’t mean picking a random uniform number from $[0,1]$ but a random uniform number with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma^2=1?$, and this is a uniform number from $[-\sqrt3,+\sqrt3]?$ Just grasping at straws, really. A lot of distributions are parametrized by mean and variance.

Comment: The problem does explicitly list $X_1,...X_{100}$ ~ $Unif(0,1)$, so at this point there seems to be two possibilities: there is the assumption you specified (although that removes a need for using $\epsilon$ as used, which has the appearance of being there for it's standard infintesimal usage), or the assignment simply has a mistake on it. I'll probably write what was in this post and conclude "thus, this problem is incorrect" or something...

Comment: I would consider discussing this problem with whoever assigned it and asking if there might be a typo in it before submitting it, but it's up to you.